# Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-like

I'm writing a query with a filter based on a string inside the field. However and I'm running the query it shows the error:

> Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar

I want to fFilter by everyone who bought a BMW based on a `custom_field`.

This is the sample data that is inside the custom field:

```
{ "car_model;":"BMWZ4", "car_id":"0980291", "manufacture":"bmw" }
```

Code:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    Last_name,
    country,
    custom_field
FROM 
    sales_table
WHERE 
    custom_field LIKE '%BMWZ4%'
```

Expected result

```
first_name: John   
last_name: Parker      
country: Germany   
custom_field: {"car_model;":"BMWZ4","car_id":"098222291","brand":"bmw"}
```

Comment: What's the type of your `custom_field`?

Comment: The field type is varchar

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: Looks like your engine supports JSON as a data type, you have to look into the vendor specific syntax for querying json.  Which vendor is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column `custom_field` is not a random string. It is specifically a JSON string. In fact, it might not be stored as a string at all, using a binary format called JSONB.

Databases that support JSON (which nowadays is pretty much all the major ones) all have bespoke JSON functions. You should be using these functions to extract patterns and values.

Often, treating the JSON column as its proper type results in more efficient queries than treating it as a string. Some databases even permit indexes on JSON columns.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
first_name,
Last_name,
country,
custom_field
FROM sales_table
WHERE cast( custom_field as varchar(max)) LIKE '%BMWZ4%'
```

Comment: SYNTAX_ERROR line 22:5: Unknown type: varchar(max)

Comment: Change varchar(max) to your systems equivalent, eg varchar(4000) or whatever

Comment: I would not recommend this even if the cast works, the resulting query is inefficient